# VLC Pitch Control or accelerated playback?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, audiobook

Is there a method, using VLC, to make an audio track play faster than normal? If so how do I go about doing it? I'd like some audio books I have to play twice as fast (+100%).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's two methods.

You can go to the menu bar and go to: `Playback` > `Faster` or `Slower`

Also on the actual player there is a way to alter the speed, there should be a box showing `1.00x` clicking this will allow you to drag a slider to change play speed.

Comment: The two methods have the same effect.

Comment: Yes but I'm just discussing all possible options available

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the hotkeys `+` and `-` to adjust the playback speed (±0.5/1.0x). There’s also `[` and `]` to adjust the speed using finer increments (0.1x), and `=` to reset the speed to 1.0x.

(I used to predominantly use WMP as my media player. I liked that VLC had the ability to adjust the speed of playback, but it also changed the pitch which made it useless. MPC has the ability to adjust the speed, but it’s limited. Gom is actually pretty good too; it can adjust the speed by 0.1x and doesn’t mess the pitch. But, when VLC changed it to leave the pitch alone, I permanently switched all my video playback to VLC because it allows me to get through things faster. I now watch pretty much *everything* at between 1.2-1.7x of normal speed, whether it’s a movie or show or whether it’s something I like or hate. In my opinion, this function of VLC is the greatest thing to happen to computers since flying, toasted, sliced bread!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, down on the status bar along the bottom, towards the right you will see a `1.00x` in a box. Click that and a drop down will show with a slider. Move the slider up and down to select the speed you want.

At the bottom of the slider it displays the current speed. Click that indicator to reset to `1.00x` again