# Can I change the pitch using VLC?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

I know [VLC can slow down / accelerate audio without changing the pitch](https://superuser.com/questions/273413/vlc-pitch-control-or-accelerated-playback). What I would like to do is the opposite, **change the pitch** (hopefully by units of semitones) and **keep the tempo**. Can it be done with VLC?

Or at least, 
can i change the pitch, even if the tempo gets changed as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, VLC can do this.  Go to:

Tools -> "Effects and Filters" -> Audio -> Advanced

It can adjust the pitch (without changing tempo)
up to one octave (12 semitones) up or down.  It indicates fractional
semitones as x.0  x.3  x.5  x.8 .  (I don't know if these are actually
steps of quarters of semitones (ie eighth-tones) or "continuous" or what.)

I know that this feature works on vlc 3.0.4 (Linux),
but I have no idea when the feature was introduced.

(BTW, this seems to be essentially the same as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1161959/how-to-change-audio-pitch-while-playing))

Edit:
On further digging, I see that on Windows (at least with VLC 3.0.7.1),
it works exactly as described above, except that you may have to widen
the "Effects" window or click on the right-arrow to display the "Advanced" tab.)

On Mac OSX, I found the "Audio Effects" menu
    (View -> "Show Audio Effects Button",  then click button on lower right)
Unfortunately, I could not find the "Adjust Pitch" effect,
nor even an "Advanced" tab.

Comment: One octave is not enough in [my use case](https://superuser.com/questions/1644058/shifting-ultrasounds-to-audible-range-in-vlc). I'd need 3 or 4 octaves. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: For Mac it is in Preferences -> Show All (bottom left) -> Audio -> Filters -> Audio pitch changer... However I found that changing the "Pitch Shift" value didn't change anything for me (M1 & Intel Mac)...

Comment: @MattPopovich, on Mac you need to restart VLC for the settings to take effect. See https://superuser.com/questions/1157810/can-i-change-the-pitch-using-vlc/1721038#1721038

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it on Mac, but it requires a restart of VLC:

1. Preferences > Interface > Show All
2. Audio > Filters > check `Pitch Shifter`
3. Audio > Filters > Audio Pitch Shifter > set `Pitch Shift` amount
4. restart VLC

Anytime you want to adjust the amount of Pitch Shift, you will have to restart VLC again.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how if this is possible with VLC but you can easily do it using the free **Audacity** program. Once you open a file using Audacity you can go to "Effects->Change Pitch"