# How to Change Audio Pitch while playing

Tags: audio, video, media-player

In the Audacity Audio Editor, in *Effect*, there is an option for *Change Pitch*.  You can see in the below photo *Down* and *Percent Change*.
I usually select *Down* and change the value of *Percent Change* to -19000.

[image]

I want to similarly change audio pitch while playing video, and do it live (not using a video editor).

Is there a way to do this with VLC Media Player?  I have searched, but I didn't find these options.  If it isn't possible with VLC, I would be open to a solution using any other media player.

Answer (score 3):

From [Change Video Pitch Using the **VideoLAN (VLC)** Player](http://www.quirkyscience.com/change-video-pitch/) :

> Open your VLC player. Under *Tools*, click *Preferences*, at the
>   bottom. Now, click *Audio*, at the top. Untick *Enable Time-Stretching
>   audio.* SAVE.
>
> If you play a normal video, nothing else is required. But if you find
>   a video that you are playing needs a pace and pitch adjustment,
>   quickly click on Playback, Speed, and try (at first) clicking on the
>   appropriate fine speed adjustment.

[image: VLC pref]

[image: VLC play]

---

From [How to Change the Pitch in **Windows Media Player**](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-change-the-pitch-in-windows-media-player) :

> 1. Open the audio or video file in Windows Media Player. If the file is playing in the Library window, click the bottom-right "Switch to
>      Now Playing" button. Step
> 2. Right-click anywhere in the Now Playing window, point to "Enhancements" and then select "Graphic Equalizer."
> 3. Select the graphic mode you prefer, such as individual adjustments or loose/fine groups. The icon next to the selection describes it, and
>      a textual description appears if you hover your mouse pointer over the
>      option. Step
> 4. Click and drag the sliders to change the pitch. You might notice the greatest effect around the 2 KHz slider, but what produces the
>      most effect varies between people.
> 5. Click the small "X" at the top right of the Graphic Equalizer pop-up to close the utility.

[image: WMP]

Comment: IIRC, that's not what the WMP equalizer does. What it does is adjust the weight of existing frequency components; what the OP wants is to shift *all* of the frequencies.
(I stumbled upon this post four years later, when WMP is basically dead, while trying to look for a way to change the playback speed and pitch at the same time.)

Comment: Sorry this is not the right answer. We need to "Change pitch without changing tempo". The solution requires you to change speed, which has an undesirable effect. The answer is you cannot do it in VLC (as of yet). Karaoke playing apps can do things like that. The other way is to extract the audio, change the pitch with Audicity and reinsert it. The extract/insert can be done with VLC, Avidemux etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, VLC can do this.  Go to:

Tools -> "Effects and Filters" -> Audio -> Advanced

It can adjust the pitch (without changing tempo)
up to one octave (12 semitones) up or down.  It indicates fractional
semitones as x.0  x.3  x.5  x.8 .  (I don't know if these are actually
steps of quarters of semitones (ie eighth-tones) or "continuous" or what.)

I know that this feature works on vlc 3.0.4 (Linux),
but I have no idea when the feature was introduced.

(BTW, this seems to be essentially the same as [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1157810/can-i-change-the-pitch-using-vlc))