# Shifting ultrasounds to audible range in VLC

Tags: vlc-media-player

Say I've recorded a dog whistle (signal in 20-50 kHz band) with a recorder with a sampling frequency of 128 kHz.
I'd like to shift frequencies down by a factor of 4 or so, so that it falls within audible range, and I wanna do that **in VLC**.

As pointed out in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1157810/can-i-change-the-pitch-using-vlc), one can shift frequencies down by up to 12.0 semitones (one octave, or 1/2 the original frequencies) at
`Tools > Audio Effects > Advanced > Adjust pitch [Enabled]` (VLC 3.0, Linux), but that is not enough to hear the hypothetical dog whistle.

Is there another, less limiting way to shift frequencies down in VLC?

Comment: Force sample playback at 32k (I’ll have look up how to do that when I get back to my desktop.) Might be easier in Audacity

Answer (score 0):

VLC can do this in menu
*Tools > Effects and Filters > Audio > Advanced*.
It can adjust the pitch without changing tempo, but only up to one octave
(12 semitones) up or down.

For transforming an audio recording, you could use the Swiss-knife of audio,
[Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/),
to change the pitch without changing tempo.
This is done in *Tools > Effect > Change Pitch...*

In addition, the free Audacity plugins
[Frequency Shifter](https://www.fullbucket.de/music/freqshifter.html)
(this is not a pitch shifter)
or
[DtBlkFx VST plug-in](https://rekkerd.org/dtblkfx/).
For installation, see
[Installing VST plug-ins](https://manual.audacityteam.org/man/installing_effect_generator_and_analyzer_plug_ins_on_windows.html#vst_install)
or the documentation bundled with the plugins.